# ERROR: Playwright does not support chromium on mac12-arm64

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, playwright

- Whenever I try to run "npm install" on mac OS Monterery 12.0.1 I receive this back
- Device: Macbook pro 2021 with m1pro chip
- " throw new Error(`Failed to download ${browserName}, caused by\n${e.stack}`);
  npm ERR!                   ^
  npm ERR!
  npm ERR! Error: Failed to download chromium, caused by
  npm ERR! Error: ERROR: Playwright does not support chromium on mac12-arm64 "

Node.Js v17.1.0

Comment: `Playwright does not support chromium on mac12-arm64`
Pretty clear error message.

Comment: Which version of Playwright are you using? Please file an issue in the Playwright repository, since Playwright should support mac12-arm64.